# Efficient way to insert record if it does not already exist, if it does exist get the ID and use it as foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Example tables (not actual database):

[image: Example tables]

In this example, I would have the SecurityCode(Unique), and Time. My current solution involves attempting to add a new Person using the security code, then querying the ID, then adding to the Times table. This is 3 separate statements and could likely be a lot faster. Any advice on how to optimise this?

Thanks.

Edit: I previously forgot to mention that this is normally done in a batch of 30-40 records.

I am also considering using SecurityCode as the foreign key in Times.

Comment: I suspect what you are doing is optimal.

Comment: Read about IODKU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way seemed to be to batch ignore insert all security codes, then batch insert all Times with a subquery to select the correct ID from Person.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways of achieve this, the easiest:

Try using "IF", you only need it for the first step of your statement, the last two are independent to the result of this evaluation.

Plus, save your security code in a variable, then you will save one table scan (you already have it)

```
**please note its just pseudo-code**

IF (exists select * from person where securityCode = @securityCode) then
    Step 1
End

Step 2
Step 3
```

Can you try it?

Comment: I considered saving the security code inside my application as a variable, however the quantity of security codes that come in within a day, is too many to store without using a database (12k "Times" records added every hour). That If statement seems like it would be useful, however I forgot to mention in my post that I'm processing these records in batches, would that be more efficient than:

1. INSERT INTO Person (SecurityCode) VALUES ([SecurityCode1]), [SecurityCode2])....
2. INSERT INTO Times (PersonID,Time) VALUES ((select ID from person where SecurityCode = [SecurityCode1]),[Time1])..

Comment: you can try to use an inner join and split your batch in two, matching and non matching rows, I don't know if I'm being clear

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't understand what you mean by that, could you elaborate?